# Request works in postman not IONIC

Tags: java, spring, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, postman

I'm developing an ionic app with a back-end with Java spring Boot with Spring security on it. When I tried to get a token with postman everything went well but in ionic, I got a 401 HTTP code. I have no cors problem, I have disabled it in my browser.

Here is the code from Ionic:

```
login() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var credentials = "grant_type=password" + "&username=admin" + "&password=admin";
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic c2NhbnRhYm91ZmZlOlhZN2ttem9OemwxMDA=');
        console.log(headers.toString);
        this.http.post('http://localhost:8443/oauth/token', credentials, {
                headers: headers
            })
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res);
                let data = JSON.parse("" + res.toString); // res.json();

                this.token = data.token;
                this.storage.set('token', data.token);
                resolve(data);

                resolve(JSON.parse("" + res.toString) /* res.json() */ );
            }, (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
}
```

Thx for yr help I'm stuck on it for more than 3 weeks